# Regex "1 Month, -$7.50" to replace "-$7.50" with "-10%"

Tags: php, regex

This is my attempt, but it's not working. I'm so rusty at regex these days so I have no idea what's wrong with it. Any help?

```
$pattern = '/-\$[.*]$/';
```

Comment: Replace the square braces with parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `*` outside of the `[]` (or better yet, use a `+`).

Try `'/-\$[0-9\.]+/'`:

```
$pattern = '/-\$[0-9\.]+/';
```

Or, if -$7.50 will always be at the end of the line:

```
$pattern = '/-\$[0-9\.]+$/';
```

Comment: @Smamatti Edited to remove the last $.  Was this specified in the question?

Comment: Sorry. I just thought the solution should be more generic. Is that wrong, becuase it wasn't specified this way?

Comment: @Smamatti Nothing wrong with that, I just thought I was was going blind for a second :).

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '/-\$(.*)$/';
```

If I understood well. The number will be accessible as "$1" in the replace string

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$pattern = '/-\$\d+\.\d+/';
```

It will match minus sign (if you change it into `-?`, minus will be optional), digits, dot and digits after dot.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $string = 'Wow! -$7.50 now!';
    $pattern = '/-\$(\d+)\.(\d+)/';

    $replacement = '-10%';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Comment: Put the minus sign into the expression.